# Auto-moving image on drag listener

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, onclicklistener, drag, ontouchlistener

I set a drag listener to an `ImageView` in my app, but when I click it, I don't want it to center the image based on where I pressed. It does this:

https://gfycat.com/ConstantDisguisedKudu

Basically, if I press on `bottom right` of the image, it takes where I press as `central point` and moves image's `center point` on that exact location. But I don't want it to do that. If I press on `bottom right` , it shouldn't auto move itself and I can drag the image from that point. I don't think any code is necessary but just in case:

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        // Signal for the start of drag and drop operation
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: {
            // do nothing
            break;
        }
        // The drag point has entered the bounding box of the View
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED: {
            // do nothing
            break;
        }
        // The user has moved the drag shadow outside the bounding box of the view
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED: {
            // do nothing
            break;
        }
        // Drag shadow has been released, the drag point is within the bounding box of the view
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: {
            // Get the image and its position
            ImageView view = (ImageView) event.getLocalState();
            int position = (int) view.getTag(R.id.piece_position);

            /**
             * If it is dropped on the left pane, remove it from its parent and also
             * remove the bitmap at the position and notify the adapter.
             * Add it to the left pane and set the position.
             */
            if (v == puzzlePane) {
                ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                viewgroup.removeView(view);

                if (position != -1) {
                    pieces.remove(position);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                FrameLayout containView = (FrameLayout) v;
                containView.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.setTag(R.id.piece_state, "left");
                view.setTag(R.id.piece_position, -1);
                view.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                view.setOnTouchListener(mAdapter);
            } else {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.setTag(R.id.piece_state, "right");
                view.setOnTouchListener(null);
                view.setOnLongClickListener(mAdapter);
            }

            Log.d(MyDragListener.class.getSimpleName(), view.getTag(R.id.piece_state) + "");

            view.setX(event.getX() - (view.getWidth() / 2));
            view.setY(event.getY() - (view.getHeight() / 2));

            break;
        }
        // The drag and drop operation has concluded
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: {
            // do nothing
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend **View.DragShadowBuilder** , and send the location of your finger relative to the continer. Something like that:

```
//where you trigger the dragging
View yourImage; //

yourImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final ClipData dragData = new ClipData("label", new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}, null);
        startDrag(dragData,  // the data to be dragged
                new MyDragShadowBuilder(v, event.getX(), event.getY()), // the drag shadow builder
                null,
                0          // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
        );
        return true;
    }
});
```

And the class:

```
private static class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

    int width, height, relativeX, relativeY;

    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v, float relativeX,float relativeY) {
        super(v);
        this.relativeX = (int) relativeX;
        this.relativeY = (int) relativeY;
        width = (v.getWidth());
        height = (v.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics (@NonNull Point size, @NonNull Point touch){
        size.set(width, height);
        touch.set(relativeX, relativeY);
    }

}
```

Comment: This almost solved the problem. Only problem is, after I stop dragging it, it positions the image awkwardly. How should I do the positioning?

If I do:

                    view.setX(event.getX());
                    view.setY(event.getY());

It sets the top left corner of the image to where I stop dragging. If I do:

                    view.setX(event.getX() - (view.getWidth() / 2));
                    view.setY(event.getY() - (view.getHeight() / 2));

Then it centers the image but still leads to awkward situations.

Comment: I got it correctly now. I'll add a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem. Only thing I added was:

            firstX = e.getX();
            firstY = e.getY();
            view.setTag(R.id.firstX, firstX);
            view.setTag(R.id.firstY, firstY);

I put the tags for the first location of ACTION_DOWN, and after the drag ended, I set the location to:

                    float firstX = (float) view.getTag(R.id.firstX);
                    float firstY = (float) view.getTag(R.id.firstY);
                    view.setX(event.getX() - firstX);
                    view.setY(event.getY() - firstY);